# Form brush painting

Tags: c#

This is the code what executes at the boot of my program. (Creates flat box)

```
e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Lime, 469, 132, 175, 28);
```

The problem is, I can't find a way to change to change its color afterwards.

The event has to be _Paint to accept e.Graphics use, can someone explain what i am missing?

Comment: What is the control that generates the event you have mentioned? Rgds,

Comment: On the boot it is: private void ModMenu_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)            I would need trigger for button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gathered you're talking about a Windows Form. If so, in the Windows Forms Framework all controls inherit from the `Control` class. This `Control` class exposes a `Refresh` method that when called, it causes the control to invalidate its client area and redraw itself which means that the `Paint` event is triggered...so simply call the `Refresh` method and manipulate the Graphic object from the `Paint` event. Here's an example...

```
SolidBrush brush;

protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Linen); //<--- set the brush color
        this.Refresh(); 
}

protected void myForm_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, 469, 132, 175, 28);
}
```

because `this` refers to the form, when you call `this.Refresh()` it causes the form to trigger the `Paint` event, so you must set the brush you want to use before calling `Refresh`

Comment: Code example would be nice :)